# Host root domain on CloudControl

Tags: dns, cloudcontrol

I want to host a root domain like "example.com". The Alias addon allows you to host sub domains like "www.example.com".

But how to host the root domain "example.com" on cloudcontrol? Because I want to create a redirect from example.com to www.example.com.

I have already setup an alias from www.example.com to my cloudControl app successfully. But I was not able to setup an alias from example.com to my cloudControl app.

I'm not sure, whether I have understood everything with the Alias addon.

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: I edited again because I thought you accidentally edit at the same time I did. If you don't like my changes feel free to change it back

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't add a CNAME to a root romain you can't link it directly to cloudControl.

The ugly way would be to manually create A-records to the (currently 3) cloudControl-loadbalancer-IPs, but cloudControl changes these (adds/removes loadbalancers) sometimes so you shouldn't do this.

For my apps I usually use the "URL"-record-type many DNS-Providers provide. In the background they use A-records to a seperate webserver that returns a redirect to the www-version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have tried to add the three loadbalancer ips from cloudControl as A DNS Record and it works perfectly.

@cloudControl, do you provide an mailing list for technical changes in the future, where you announce changes on your loadbalancer ips? Would be really nice :)

The bad thing is, my domain hoster don't support DNS Records for URL Forwarding :(

Comment: Unfortunately this approach really isn't feasible since the changes are usually on very short notice. As long as you use the 3 fixed adresses only for a redirect to the www. version you should be fine. We never go below 3 nodes in the routing tier, so those 3 IPs should never change. But officially we do not support A records so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a service like DNS Made Easy. They provide a custom type called ANAME, that's basically a CNAME without the CNAME limitations. They take care of updating the IP addresses in the background when necessary.

http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/technology/aname-records/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have looked into this service, but for an non commercial project without any income, it is a little bit expensive :( - I have already added a comment to the other answer, maybe you can have a look into my proposal :)

Comment: Good to know there is a way to handle naked domains. $30/y is affordable for our project :-)